# How to calculate a Hohmann transfer when the target is moving retrograde

Tags: orbital-mechanics, hohmann-transfer, retrograde-orbit

Exactly as the title says. I have two objects, both in circular orbits, and with the target object in a higher, retrograde orbit. How do I modify the Hohmann transfer formulae to find the angular distance that should be between them at the start of the transfer burn?

Comment: I don't think Hohmann transfer is the right term for this. It's not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve: do you want the lower object to burn to a rendezvous with the target object, so that they both end up in the higher retrograde orbit at the same place at the same time, or an impact with the target object, where their velocities don't need to match, only their positions at a certain time?

Comment: Is the lower object in a prograde orbit? If so, rndz is, in practice, impossible.

Comment: if you're asking a question about modifying a specific formula, please include that formula in your question. At the very least, it will help answerers explain how to modify the formula you're familiar with to do what you want it to do.

Comment: This would no longer be a Hohmann transfer. One could call it a Hohmann-like transfer in the sense that what you are asking for is still a two burn solution. However, a transfer that involves more than two burns such as the bielliptic-like transfer (a three burn solution) as outlined in @uhoh's answer could significantly reduce the total $\Delta v$.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer until a real orbital mechanic writes a good one with some math in it.

The [Hohmann transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit) elliptical orbit is started with a prograde impulse, and when you reach the apoapsis of the higher orbit a second prograde impulse raises your semimajor axis (and speed) to circularize.

The brute force method to match the *retrograde* higher circular orbit is to replace the 2nd prograde impulse with a *much bigger* retrograde impulse. I have to [go eat some cherry blossoms](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/126738/61071) this morning before the crowds show up, so I won't add the algebra. Basically you just use the [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation)

$$v^2 = GM \left(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a} \right)$$

where the product $GM$ is the [standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) for your central body.

**However** why not consider a [Bi-elliptic transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-elliptic_transfer) where you do a "first Hohman" to a very high orbit, where the 2nd impulse can be much smaller. You are so high up that you move very slowly, so reversing direction is a lot less costly.

Once in a retrograde very high up, you do a "second Hohman" to drop back down to the high retrograde orbit where you do a third and now prograde impulse to slow down and match the retrograde circular orbit.